# Pagination while scrolling in Swift Firebase

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am loading data from Firebase Database. I am trying to load data while user scrolls. For example if he has scrolled about 20 `cells` then I want to load a little more about 5 `cells`. I am trying to achieve it like this but it is not working:

```
func parseSnusBrands(){
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")

        ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToLast(20).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                if let all = (snapshot.value?.allKeys)! as? [String]{
                    self.snusBrandsArray = all
                    self.snusBrandsTableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

and to detect how many cells are scrolled:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 20 {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")

        ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimitedToLast(20).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                if let all = (snapshot.value?.allKeys)! as? [String]{
                    self.snusBrandsArray = all
                    self.snusBrandsTableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is my **Firebase** structure:

[image]

Is there better solution or should I keep trying like this?

[Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/6KmwyikYAed9FaH7hvSGGi) you can see the whole code. I know that it lacks of OO but I am learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `offset` to achieve pagination in your app.

First, add an `order` key in your child path, may be current time stamp of insertion so that you can order it and use it in pagination.

For eg.

```
"brands": {
         "catch" : {
           ...
           ...
           "pOrder" : 555
         },
         "etan" : {
           ...
           ...
           "pOrder" : 444
         },
         "general" : {
           ...
           ...
           "pOrder" : 555
         }.
         .....
       }
```

Now, to achieve pagination you would retrieve 21 records and in those records, the first 20 will be the records to use in table view, while the last record will be the `offset` that will be used to retrieve next set of records.

Create a function that fetches data from `firebase`:

```
 // MARK: Retrieving Data: Firebase
    /*
     retrieve current set of posts sorted by updated time of posts
     */
    func retrievePost(offset: NSNumber, callFlag: Bool, completion: (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?)->()){
        // As this method is called from viewDidLoad and fetches 20 records at first.
        // Later when user scrolls down to bottom, its called again
        let postsRef = ref.child(kDBPostRef)
        var startingValue:AnyObject?
        // starting  value will be nil when this method is called from viewDidLoad as the offset is not set

        if callFlag{
            if offset == 0{
                startingValue = nil
            }
            else{
                startingValue = offset
            }
        } else{
            // get offset from the offsetArray
            startingValue = self.findOffsetFromArray()

        }
        // sort records by pOrder fetch offset+1 records
        self.refHandler = postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("pOrder").queryStartingAtValue(startingValue).queryLimitedToFirst(kPostLimit + 1).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // flag is for setting the last record/ 21st as offset
            var flag = 0

            let tempPost = NSMutableSet()
                // iterate over children and add to tempPost
                for item in snapshot.children {

                    // check for offet, the last row(21st) is offset ; Do not add last element in the main table list
                    flag += 1
                    if flag == 21 && callFlag == true{
                        // this row is offset
                        self.kOffset = item.value?["pOrder"] as! NSNumber
                        self.offSetArray?.append(self.kOffset)
                        continue
                    }
                    // create Post object
                    let post = Post(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)

                    // append to tempPost
                    tempPost.addObject(post)
                }
                // return to the closure
                completion(result:tempPost, error:nil)
        })
    }
```

And call this `updateNewRecords` method from `viewDidLoad`, passing `0` to retrieve first 20 records.

```
 func updateNewRecords(offset:NSNumber, callFlag: Bool){
        self.retrievePost(offset,callFlag:callFlag) { (result,error) -> Void in
//            let tempArray = result as! [Post]
            let oldSet = Set(self.posts)
            var unionSet = oldSet.union(result as! Set<Post>)
            unionSet = unionSet.union(unionSet)
            self.posts = Array(unionSet)
            self.postsCopy = self.posts
//          print(self.posts.count)
            self.posts.sortInPlace({ $0.pOrder> $1.pOrder})
            self.reloadTableData()
        }
    }
```

Again when the user scrolls to bottom in the `table view`, call this method,  `updateNewRecords` passing the offset, to retrieve next set of 20 records.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

        // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
        let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

        // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
        if maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0 {
            self.updateNewRecords(self.kOffset, callFlag:true)
        }
    }
```

You can maintain an array `offsetArray` for updating table values when your data is modified in `firebase` .

For e.g. suppose some data is modified somewhere in your table, in that case `observeEventType` will be called and you should fetch only those range of records from `firebase`. You can achieve it using maintaining an array of `offsets`. So when any record is updated, the `retrievePost` will be called with the corresponding `offset` from `offsetArray`. In normal case, ( while retrieving data from `viewDidLoad` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging`), the offset will be `kOffset` and in rest of the cases(while listening to data change), the offset will be from `offsetArray`.

You can define a function that will return the `offset` value for a particular updated column:

```
// find the offset from the offsetDict
    func findOffsetFromArray() -> NSNumber{
        let idx = self.kClickedRow/20 // kClickedRow is the updated row in the table view
        return self.offSetArray![idx]

    }
```

You can also modify `retrievePost` method and pass an extra parameter to retrieve a certain number of records.

Comment: What do you mean by kOffset and findOffsetFromArray. Do I have to create another array?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp I have added more explanation about the `offsetAray` and `kOffset`.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely good and I accept it but I think I am not going further with it. It is too confusing :D Isn't there any easier way to achieve this? Is there any working example maybe you know?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp I am not sure about any working e.g. bu you can try reading this post (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html). It might help you!

Comment: Can you help me to implement this?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Yes .. Can we move this conversation to chat