# Firebase - Managing user likes in an efficient way - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where a user can like things in the app, it is for obvious reasons that a user shouldnt be able to like something twice. To make sure of this, when a user likes something, I store the key of the article in a list on the database. The problem is what is the most efficient way when the table view is loading to check if the user has liked the article already.

But after that I need advice, the way I see it I have two ways I can do this.

1. I can load the entire list when the app starts and then when the table view loads I can check if the article key is in the list of already likes keys. (This is what I am leaning toward) The only problem with this is when a user has liked say 1000 things then everytime the app starts it will have to download 1000 rows from Firebase which is a lot, the other problem means that the articles can't start loading until this query is done.
2. Pass the article key into the cell and then query the database for that key to see if it exists, the reason I worry about this is because that means there will be a query every time a cell loads and thats alot of queries and network activity. I am unsure if that will be a problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest not to prevent the duplication of "likes" on the client-side; it would end up being too exhaustive as you described. There are two things you can do:

1. You can prevent duplication by structuring your database as follows:

   ```
   {
     "likes": {
        "user1Key": {
           "objectLikedKey1": true,
           "objectLikedKey2": true
           ...
        }
      }
   }
   ```

This way, the data structure would prevent duplication by default. Think of it like a set!

2. If your database is structured differently and for some reason you need it that way, you can use a rule to prevent duplication. (I'll just assume a random structure here so you can get the idea)

   ```
   {
     "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        "userLikes": {
           "$user": {
              ".write": "!data.exists()"
           }
        }
      }
   }
   ```

This means you can only write to the database if the data does not already exist.

**Update:**

Create a child in the structure for every object, each containing a list of all the users who "liked" said object

```
    {
      "objects": {
         "object1Key": {
            "user1Key": true,
            "user2Key": true
            ...
            "timestamp": "2017-01-01 12:00:00 +0000"
          }
       }
    }
```

The structure in point (1) would be useful if you want to retrieve all the objects some user liked. The latter structure should be used if you want to retrieve all the users that liked a certain object.

If you have some kind of Facebook-like newsfeed table that loads posts or objects, then the second approach would be best and it would also prevent duplication of likes. You might also want to implement some kind of paging mechanism in your table that loads a reasonable number (let's say 5 or 10) objects when the user scrolls to view more. Each time you retrieve a page of objects, loop through the users who liked that object and check if the currently logged in user is one of them, if they are, set the button's color appropriately.

It'll take up some memory if you have a lot of activity, but it's your best approach for now. I believe the most memory efficient solution would be looping through the objects' likes process on the server instead of the clients' devices so you can just retrieve a boolean whether the user liked it or not, but Firebase doesn't provide that option.

**Implementation tips:**

-If you're actually going for the paging mechanism suggested above, you can use the following method to check if you need to load more items:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let lastElement = yourDataSource.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // load more
        }    
}
```

-Pagination would require some kind of marker to set which items should be retrieved, so you should probably store a timestamp with each object you add in your structure (along with the list of the users who liked that object as shown above). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705925/pagination-while-scrolling-in-swift-firebase) has a detailed answer about pagination. If you're familiar with `queryOrderedByChild()`, `queryStartingAtValue()`, and `queryLimitedToFirst()`, you'll get the idea easily, maybe without going through the answer in the link!

Comment: I like this method! But by app design the like button turns blue when a user likes it, how can i make it so that if they have already liked it the button is already blue? Without having the problems i mentioned above?