# Difference between three firebase storage download methods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I couldn't find resources discussing the difference between the three [download methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_files) in the firebase storage documentation and pros/cons of each. I would like some clarification about the firebase storage documentation.

**My App**

- Displays 100 images ranging from 10 KB-500 KB in size on a table view
- Will be used in a location where internet connection and/or phone service could be very weak
- Could be used by many users

**3 methods for downloading from Firebase storage**

1. Download to `NSData` in memory

   > This is the easiest way to quickly download a file, but it must load entire contents of your file into memory. If you request a file larger than your app's available memory, your app will crash. To protect against memory issues, make sure to set the max size to something you know your app can handle, or use another download method.

**Question:** I tried this method to display 100 images that were 10KB-500KB in size on my table view cells. Although my app didn't crash, as I scrolled through my table, my memory usage increased to 268 mb. Would this method ***not*** be recommended for displaying a lot of images?

2. Download to an `NSURL` representing a file on device

   > The `writeToFile:completion:` method downloads a file directly to a local device. Use this if your users want to have access to the file while offline or to share in a different app.

**Question:** Does that mean all images from firebase storage will be downloaded on user's phone? Does that mean that the app will be taking up a large percentage of the available storage on the phone?

3. Generate an `NSURL` representing the file online

> If you already have download infrastructure based around URLs, or just want a URL to share, you can get the download URL for a file by calling the `downloadURLWithCompletion:` method on a storage reference.

**Question:** Does this method require a strong internet connection and/or phone service connection to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, your memory usage should not be affected by the method of retrieval. As long as you're displaying the 100 images, their data will be stored in the memory and should have the same size if they're identically formatted/compressed.

Either way you go with, I suggest you implement pagination (for your convenience, this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705925/pagination-while-scrolling-in-swift-firebase/38706838#38706838) might serve as a good implementation reference/guide) to possibly decrease the memory and network usage.

Now, down to comparing the methods:

- **Method 1**

  > ...but it must load entire contents of your file into memory.

  This line might throw some people off thinking it's a
  memory-inefficient solution, when all it really means is that you
  cannot retrieve parts of the data, you can only download the entire
  file. In the case of storing images, you probably would want that for
  the data to make sense.

  If your application needs to download the images every time the users
  access it (i.e if your images are regularly updated), then this
  method will probably suit you best. The images will be downloaded
  every time the application starts, then they'll get discarded when
  you kill it.

  You stated that a part of your user base might have a weak internet
  connection and so the next method might be more efficient and
  user-friendly
- **Method 2**

  First off, the answers to your questions:

  1. Yes. The images downloaded using this method will be stored on the users' devices.
  2. The images should take up about the same size they're taking on Firebase storage.

  Secondly, if you plan to use this method, then I suggest you store a
  timestamp (or any sort of marker) in your database for when the last
  change to the images occurred. Then, every time the app opens up, do
  the following flow:

  1. If no images are downloaded -> download images and store the database timestamp locally
  2. If the local timestamp does not equal the timestamp on the database -> download images and store the new timestamp locally
  3. Else -> use the images you already have, they should be identical to the ones in Firebase storage

  That would be the best way to go if your network usage priority is
  higher than that of the local storage.

  And finally...
- **Method 3 (not really)**

  This is **not** a data download method, this simply generates a
  download URL given a reference to the child. You can then use that
  URL to download the data in your app or elsewhere as long as the used
  app or API is authorized to access your Firebase storage.

  **Update:**

  The URL is generated from a Firebase reference (`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("exampleReference")`) and would look like this: (Note: this is a fake link that will not actually work, just used for illustration purpose)

  ```
  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectName.appspot.com/o/somePathHere%2FchildName%2FsomeOtherChildName%2FimageName.jpg?alt=media&token=1a8f83a7-95xf-4d3s-nf9b-99a274927bcb
  ```

  If you simply try to access that link you generate through any regular web-browser (assuming you don't have any Firebase `rule` that conflicts with that in your project), you can directly download that image from *anywhere*, not just through your app.

  So in conclusion, this "Method" does ***not*** download data from Firebase storage, it just returns a download URL for your data in case you want a direct link.

Comment: I'm confused about this line for Method 2: "if your network usage priority is higher than that of the local storage." By network usage priority, do you mean my memory usage?. For method 3, when you say "use that URL to download the data in your app" is that the same as method 2, where images downloaded are "stored on the users' devices"?

Comment: What I meant by the line you're asking about in Method 2 is that if you value your users' internet usage more than space taken up on their devices, go for this method. If you don't mind them downloading all the images every time they use the app, then you don't need to store them on the device.

I expanded a bit about the 3rd method in the answer for clarification. Let me know if you're still confused about it!

Comment: okay, for method 3, does that require a strong wifi connection and/or good cell service?

Comment: Generating the URL requires minimal connection. However, using the URL to download the image/data would require the same as any of the 2 previous methods.